# Colon and $ in makefile

Tags: makefile

What does `TEMP0_FILES` below compute to? `SOURCE_FILES` can equal to multiple source files. Please tell me the purpose of the following syntax `:.cpp=.o`

```
SOURCE_FILES = main.cpp

TEMP0_FILES = $(SOURCE_FILES:.cpp=.o)
```

Comment: What has become of the good old tradition of reading the fine manual?

Comment: @Jens Appreciate this is a 10 year old comment, but - it never hurts to have help knowing where to look. I would've had no idea where to find this information in the `make` manual until I knew what it did. This SO question, on the other hand, answered my question very helpfully :)

Comment: Still trying to find it in the manual. Who know it was hard to look for something that has literal no keywords. "variable, colon, makefile" was basically all I could search for. Only because of Andy's answer I could find the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Substitution-Refs.html)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The : syntax causes a substitution to occur on the variable.  In this case it will replace ".cpp" with ".o" in all of the items in the SOURCE_FILES variable.

TEMP0_FILES will be "main.o"

If SOURCE_FILES is "main.cpp otherfile.cpp otherfile2.cpp" TEMP0_FILES will become:  "main.o otherfile.o otherfile2.o" etc.