# colon in makefile

Tags: makefile

I saw the following in a code once in a Makefile. What is the colon in the middle means?

```
 export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/e3rd/lib:/3rd/im/lib
```

It doesn't look like the same as the colon from [Colon and $ in makefile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784392/colon-and-in-makefile).

It be nice too if you can tell me what is the potential use of it as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's just a separator for paths. It's a syntax for separating paths in LD_LIBRARY_PATH. Nothing to do with makefile.

Comment: can you tell me what is the potential use of the separator there and when to use it maybe even better with an example? :)

Comment: @user1655072: this line indicates that LD_LIBRARY_PATH (i.e. the place where to search for shared libraries) is composed of two directories. Usage of `:` for separating directories in environment variables is fairly standard (POSIX defines it for the `PATH` variable, that indicates where to search for executables)